# URLClassLoader not loading the resources

Tags: java, exception, jar, classloader, urlclassloader

I have written a program which manages a plugin which is provided as jar.

I load the plugin classes using an `URLClassLoader` which works as it's supposed to.
I had added some resources (XML file) which are stored in the plugin jar.

If I invoke a method that doesn't use resources, everything works fine, but if I invoke a method that uses resources I get a `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Posting some of your code would be helpful

Comment: invoke() method :load class , getResourceAsStream():load resource ,is there any way to relate these two method , i want that invoke method reference to getResourceAsStream Method

Answer (score 0):

The resources packaged inside your plugin jar file are loaded by your `URLClassLoader`. So to access those resources, you should use that particular `URLClassLoader` instance to load them.

Eg:

```
URL[] urls = ...//urls to jar classes and resources
URLClassLoader uClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class loadedClass = uClassLoader.loadClass("CLASS_NAME");
```

To get the resource present in the jar,

```
loadedClass.getClassLoader().getResource()
```

Note, here the `URLClassLoader` instance is used to load the resources.

For more details on loading the resources:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

Hope this solves your issue.